# CKeditor integration throwing Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. on focus of text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, forums, pluck

I am working on pluck integration with our ecommerce site - Pluck integration forums include a ckeditor where a user can type and post in to a forum.

But with our integration, upon clicking the ck editor text area i am getting the following error:

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at d.window.focus (ckeditor.js?v=cebd:formatted:1378)

I am not sure what could be the possible reason for this, as this error comes only on focus / click of the text area in ckeditor.

Any body has faced similar issues in ckeditor please reply here.

Any ideas on what all could be the possible reason for this error would be helpful